# Rails Beginner NoMethodError in PinsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

having issues keep getting error undefined method `pins' for nil:NilClass, can someone explain how to fix this error. Been following a tutorial and recently got stuck.

---

pins_controller.rb

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


    def index
        @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def new
        @pin = current_user.pins.build
    end


    def create
        @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)

        if @pin.save
            redirect_to @pin, notice: "Successfully created new Pin"
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit

    end

    def update
        if @pin.update(pin_params)
            redirect_to @pin, notice: "Pin was Successfully updated!"
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end


    def destroy
        @pin.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end


    private

    def pin_params
        params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description)
    end

    def find_pin
        @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

---

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    has_many :pins     
end
```

---

pin.rb

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

---

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
resources :pins

root "pins#index"
end
```

Comment: Your error is because `current_user` returns `nil`. Check that method (probably in ApplicationController)

Comment: @PetrGazarov i used the gem devise and it came with current_user, just wondering what should i be looking for.

Comment: Where did you get that error, what line?

Comment: @Lymuel i got the error on line 10, where it says current_user.pins.build

Comment: its saying that the word pins is undefined

Comment: do you have `before_action :authenticate_user!` on your**application controller**, it seems like that `current_user` is empty because there's no logged in user

Comment: @MikeShasaco, it's not. The error specifically says `undefined method 'pins' for nil:NilClass`, implying that `current_user` is nil.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using devise, you might want to add
`before_action :authenitcate_user!`
method inside pins controller which ensures that the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the gem `Devise` then the helper method `current_user` returns you the current logged in user in your session.

Pleases make sure a user is logged in/

You can make sure that the user is logged in by adding `before_action :authenitcate_user!` in your application controller(for all actions in your application).

Comment: Thank you, i wasn't logged in

Comment: Awesome, glad i could help you out.